# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'div'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am trying to run this [code file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iARH_y_jMIGbGQP1WH8ucomWcxzIzzlt/view?usp=sharing) using google colab. Although I am getting some of the outputs but an error is showing up

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'div'
```

I looked this problem up on stack overflow like most problems I face but there's no solution. Someone, please help me understand what's wrong with the code. I am completely new to TensorFlow.

NOTE: I would've pasted the whole code here but it's a 1400+ line code so I directly hyperlinked the file as people might get annoyed and moreover, by doing so this post will get very long. But if needed, I can edit the post and paste the whole code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.div` was based on the old Python 2 division scheme and has been removed.  You should use `tf.truediv` or `tf.divide` instead.